# How to append data in a PS file?

Tags: mainframe, jcl

I have the following line in a PS file

```
version
!cd "//''"
```

the another file contains the following line

```
remove
```

I want to append data from another file in between the single quotes of the above line. After Appending the characters(remove) from another the ps file should contain the following data

```
 version
!cd "/remove/''"
```

I tried using OUTREC but it din work, the characters versions also got changed

```
SORT FIELDS=COPY
OUTREC FIELDS=(1:C'!cd "/',
                6:1,6,
                12:C''"')
```

Comment: What have you tried? What data needs to be inserted? What do you mean by JCL (SORT?)? When you say "following lines" and show only one line, what do you mean. Show representative data from both your source files, and example output for that data.

Answer (score 0):

Your FIELDS (which is better as BUILD) should be conditional to avoid processing every line.

You've not mentioned how you are getting the data from the other file.

Best would be two steps. Step 1, to create a "symbol file" (SYMNAMES DD when it is used in the second step) to take the data from your second file and give it a name.

Then in the second step, with conditional processing (IFTHEN=(WHEN=(logicalexpression)) to use the value of the symbol as the insertion.

I'm assuming your second file can sometimes contain different values? If not, why not just generate the whole thing? Or use your editor?